# Com esta regra abaixo, como faço para mostrar o primeiro e o último nome do usuário no banco de dados?

Tags: php, yii

Dentro do model, como faço para mostrar o nome do usuário:
Exemplo do nome que está no DB: José ALberto da Silva Nogueira. Gostaria que mostrasse apenas José Nogueira.

```
public function getNome(){

    if($this->group == User::GROUP_NOME_CLIENTE)
        return $this->nome_cliente->ds_nome;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exemplo usando as funções de array:

```
$str = 'José Alberto da Silva Nogueira';
$arr = explode(' ', $str);
echo ((count($arr) < 2)? $str : current($arr).' '.end($arr));
```

Exemplo usando funções de strings.

```
$str = 'José Alberto da Silva Nogueira';
echo strstr($str.' ', ' ', true).strrchr($str, ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue código:

```
if($this->group == User::GROUP_NOME_CLIENTE) {
    $nomeCompleto = $this->nome_cliente->ds_nome;
    $separa = explode(" ", $nomeCompleto);
    if(count($separa) < 2){
       return $nomeCompleto;
    }
    return $separa[0] . " " . $separa[count($separa) -1];
}
```

Comment: o problema que eu tenho ainda é que se o usuário se cadastrar com um só nome (José). Daí fica replicado o nome.

Comment: alterei o código para prever esse caso colocado