# Pegar primeiro nome com Expressão Regular

Tags: php, regex, expressões

Preciso pegar o primeiro nome com expressão regular, só que não estou conseguindo corretamente. Hoje uso o código assim:

```
<?php
preg_match('/[[:alnum:]]+/i', 'Alisson Acioli', $matches);

return $matches[0];
?>
```

> Saída: Alisson

Quando o nome é composto:

```
<?php
preg_match('/[[:alnum:]]+/i', 'João', $matches);

return $matches[0];
?>
```

> Saída: Jo

Comment: Use o modificador `u` para capturar caracteres multibyte. `strstr()` já resolve isso => [Imprimindo uma String até ser encontrado um espaço](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97711/91)

Comment: E porque você precisa pegar com expressão regular?

Comment: quer mesmo fazer isso com ER?

Comment: Coincidência, acabei de ver uma pergunta similar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105977/com-esta-regra-abaixo-como-fa%C3%A7o-para-mostrar-o-primeiro-e-o-%C3%BAltimo-nome-do-usu%C3%A1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente usar esse código:

```
<?php
    preg_match('/[^\s]*/', 'Qualquer Nome', $matches);
    return $matches[0];
?>
```

Comment: Essa regex vai aceitar nomes assim também: `34566`...

Answer (score 6):

Você pediu com expressão regular, mas vou deixar algumas alternativas com operação de *string*, caso alguém prefira sem RegEx (na verdade, RegEx não é para essas coisas simples).

### Explode

```
$tokens = explode( 'Alisson Acioli', $nome );
return $tokens[0];
```

com verificação se encontrado:

```
$nome = 'Alisson Acioli';
$tokens = explode( ' ', $nome );
return count( $tokens ) > 0 ? $tokens[0] : '';
```

### Substr + strpos

```
$nome = 'Alisson Acioli';
return mb_substr( $nome, 0, mb_strpos( $nome, ' ' ) );
```

com verificação se encontrado:

```
$pos = mb_strpos( $nome, ' ' );
return $pos !== false ? mb_substr( $nome, 0, $pos ) : '';
```

### strstr

```
$nome = 'Alisson Acioli';
return mb_strstr( $nome, ' ', true );
```

Em todos os casos, o prefixo `mb_` é para *strings* multibyte. Se usar *encodings* de 1 byte só, pode retirar os prefixos.

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma de resolver com regex é:

```
$str = 'joão da silva';

preg_match('/\[a-z]+/ui', $str, $m);
```

O modificador PCRE `u` é importante nesse  caso para fazer a captura de caracteres acentuados do contrario vai captura apenas caracteres singlebyte como no exemplo da pergunta. Já o modificador `i` tornar a captura caseinsensitive ou seja tanto faze se as letras são maiusculas ou minusculas.

Outras opção de resolver esse problema veja em:  [Imprimindo uma String até ser encontrado um espaço](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97711/91)

Answer (score 2):

Podes testar com `\p{L}+`, que procura [caracteres com caracteristicas especificas](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).

Nesse caso o código ficaria assim:

```
preg_match('/\p{L}+/i', 'Alisson Acioli', $matches);
return $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso ocorre devido a acentuação da palavra **joão**, pois o `[[:alnum:]]` não considera acentuação. Considere usar:

```
preg_match('/[\p{Latin}\d]+/i', 'Joaõ da Silva', $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```